# adding arrays inside dictionaries, inside more arrays?

Tags: python

adding arrays inside dictionaries, inside more arrays.

I asked a question and Jakebird451 helped me. But i have most questions now.

```
fruits = [{
    'name':"apple",
    'color':["red","green"],
    'weight':1
}, {
    'name':"banana",
    'color':["yellow","green"],
    'weight':1
}, {
    'name':"orange",
    'color':"orange",
    'weight':[1,2]
}, {
    'name':"pear",
    'color':"orange",
    "size" : [
                    {
                        "weight" : 4,
                        "mass" : 1.6
                    },
                    {
                        "weight" : 4,
                        "mass" : 2
                    },
                    {
                        "weight" : 4,
                        "mass" : 2.5
                    }
                ]
}]
```

what if there is an another dictionary with an another array?
how do i use this function to get weight and mass?

```
def findCarByColor(theColor):
    array=[]
    for x in carList: 
        if theColor in x['Color']:
            array.append(x['name']+" "+x['weight'])
    return array
print findit2("red")
```

Comment: I have rolled back your question. Your edit did not make sense. You asked a new question: "if the number is bigger then 'stuff' then print out the name and color of the fruit whos `stuff` is bigger then the `number`". You cannot have a condition in which `number` is bigger than `stuff`, and then print the answer if `stuff` is bigger than `number`! Please ask a new question and consider the condition that you are testing for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle both cases, assuming you have the variable `fruits` as in the question:

```
def findItByColor(theColor):
    array=[]
    for x in fruits: 
        if theColor in x['color']:
            try:
                array.append(x['name']+" "+ str(x['weight']))
            except KeyError:
                size = ' '.join( [ '[Weight %s Mass %s]'
                                   % (str(item['weight']),str(item['mass']))
                         for item in x['size'] ])
                array.append( x['name']+" "+ size )
    return array

print findItByColor("orange")
```

This prints:

```
['orange [1, 2]', 'pear [Weight 4 Mass 1.6] [Weight 4 Mass 2] [Weight 4 Mass 2.5]']
```

While this query:

```
print findItByColor("green")
```

returns:

```
['apple 1', 'banana 1']
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've made weight and mass elements of the "size" key in your dictionary.

Your code would need to be modified accordingly:

```
def findCarByColor(theColor):
    array=[]
    for x in carList: 
        if theColor in x['Color']:
            array.append(x['name']+" "+x['size']['weight'] +" "+x['size']['mass'] )
    return array
print findit2("red")
```

However, this will only work for your "pear" example, since the way you're storing the weight value is not consistent.

**EDIT:**

You keep changing your underlying data structure in your example, which means the code for findCarByColor() needs to change too.

I would suggest

1. Pin down exactly what data you need to store
2. Standardize your data structure. Why is it that the dictionary for "pear" has a size list, but the others don't? By keeping your data concise and consistent whenever possible, you make manipulating it (as in your function) much simpler.

Comment: `size` key is not in all dictionaries. Perhaps you should check first?

Comment: what if the size was a value that had to be a certain number.. for example. everything that is heavier then 1

Comment: @thebiggerchadder In that case, you could add a second if statement under the first, something like if x['size']['weight'] > 1

Comment: to your pear reply. i didnt know what to make the new dictionary